# Find the intersection of the power set and a list of sets

Tags: java

Given a large arbitrary set S, and a list of sets S_n, find all of the sets in S_n that are subsets of S.

In other words, the intersection of the PowerSet(S) and S_n.

Are there any Java libraries to do this kind of math quickly?  The list of sets S_n will be relatively small, at most a few hundred, and those sets will contain at most 10 items. However, the arbitrary sets (determined at runtime) may have as many as 20 items (out of a set of 1000) and thus has a huge power set.

I'm looking for a way, perhaps doing some type of offline computation, to do this determination on the fly very quickly (50 ms or less).

Example:
S = { 1, 2, 3 }

S_n = [ { 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 5, 4, 6 } ]

Result = [ { 1 }, { 1, 2 } ]

Comment: take a gander at Set.containsAll()

Comment: Bear in mind that the iteration performance of `HashSet` is proportional to capacity as well as size, so take care when instantiating your sets.

Comment: Each set in the list of sets (S_n) will be ordered, the set S will not be initially.

Answer (score 1):

pseudo-code

```
for each subset s_n
    if (s.containsAll(s_n)) {
        add it to the result list
    }
```

Comment: This approach will probably work. I can reduce the list of sets down a fair amount on the database side by only returning sets that contain at least one element of the arbitrary set.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the standard method `retainAll(Collection<?> c)`  declared in interface `java.util.Set`

Comment: This would require me to compute the power set of a set of 20 items, that's pretty big.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give a look at Google's Guava library.

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Sets

This can count the powerset for you as well as ny additional operation on the Collections, also ensuring good performances (considering you're calculating a powerset.....).

Comment: I don't actually need the power set, that's just how I was trying to explain it. What I need to do is find each of the sets in a list of sets that are subsets of my current set quickly.

Comment: I was just mentioning that Sets also can generate the powerset. It's the intersection operation that would probably work in your case, if I understand what you need....

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Guava Sets](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html).

It has many of the utilities you need like powerSet and intersection.